# Linux if exit codes in csh

Tags: linux, if-statement, ssh, csh

How can you pass the exit code of a failed script in an if else statement in csh? e.g.

```
if ( "test" != "test" ) then
   /bin/true
else 
    /bin/false
endif

echo $?
```

gives an exit code of 0. However just running

```
/bin/false
echo $?
```

gives an exit code of 1.

It seems as if the endif just overwrites the exit code of whatever the output of the commands are within the if else statement.

```
endif 
echo $?
```

exit code: 0

So is there a better way of passing the exit code from the statement apart from setting it to a variable after running each of the commands?

e.g.

```
if ( "test" != "test" ) then
   /bin/true
   set exitcode = $?
else 
    /bin/false
   set exitcode = $?
endif
```

The /bin/false and /bin/true are just examples of scripts in those positions either failing of succeeding, and how the endif overrides their exit codes. So the exits codes of either of these statements could be anything [0-255]. I'm not trying to capture a simple 1 or 0.

**UPDATE**

The below suggestion by Thomas seems to work if you create a csh script.

```
#!/bin/csh
if ( "test" != "test" ) then
    /bin/true
    exit $?
else 
    /bin/false
    exit $?
endif
```

But it doesn't appear to work if using ssh

```
ssh -A -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null $USER@`hostname` '
>if ( "test" != "test" ) then
>    /bin/true
>    exit $?
>else 
>    /bin/false
>    exit $?
>endif'
echo $?
0
```

Comment: If you set variables, then the `true` program needs not be executed, the final result is as succinct as the original one.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use exit:

```
#!/bin/csh
if ( "test" != "test" ) then
    /bin/true
    exit $?
else 
    /bin/false
    exit $?
endif
```

exit can handle 1byte exit codes [0-255]

Comment: The /bin/true and /bin/false are just examples of commands that were being run either failing or succeeding. I'm looking for the exit codes of the scripts being run. To check whether the scripts have failed or not. I'll try and make that clearer in the question above.